# String replace from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, string, str-replace

I want to replace the abbreviation of word by using database. here's my code so far

```
public function singkatan ($temp) {
    $sg = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT singkatan FROM dictionary WHERE singkatan='$temp'"));
    $wd = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE singkatan='$temp'"));
    $kembalian = str_replace($sg[0],'$wd[0]',$temp);
    return $kembalian;
}
```

but, it doesn't work.

Comment: remove the quotes in replace

Comment: Side note: why not combine those two queries into one? E.g. `SELECT singkatan, word FROM dictionary...` *Edit:* after reading your code a little more, surely the `$sg` line is just returning what you're passing in as `$temp` anyway, so is a redundant database call?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do all the work to mysql with its function REPLACE:

```
$sg = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT REPLACE(dictionary.singkatan,dictionary.word,'$temp') 
FROM dictionary WHERE dictionary.singkatan='$temp'"));
return $sg[0];
```